# Page not found in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm following [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/) tutorial to learn Django. I'm a total starter.
My urls.py file has following code

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

 ]
```

My views.py file is

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
 return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

When i try to access th url http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/ in my system it gives a page not found message. What am i doing wrong?
Is it a problem with the version difference?

Here is the screenshot of the error
[image]

Comment: Did you include your app in `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py`?

Comment: @Leistungsabfall yes i have included that.

Comment: So what's in polls.urls?

Comment: Polls is my app and urls.py id the python file that contains the code given in the question. I think polls.urls is referring to the same

Comment: pools.url should be a different urls config, could you paste it ?

Comment: I cannot find polls.urls anywhere inside my directory. Content inside the url file is in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error comes if your urls.py file in polls directory does not have this pattern. Create a file urls.py your polls directory and add following url pattern

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# ex: /polls/
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

Comment: Can you show your polls/urls.py file. Because if there was this pattern then the error page would also have shown that. And currently it is not showing in your screenshot.

Comment: Also if you see the tutorials it may be clear to you

Comment: No, you have to add that pattern in another file urls.py which is inside the polls directory, not in this file itself.

Comment: Yes, the code above is in urls.py file which is inside polls folder

Comment: Ok, then remove the 2nd and 3rd pattern of your code and add them to urls.py file which is immediately inside your project directory.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so if you want to use `/polls/` with this urls, 
your polls.urls should look similar to this ( for django1.8):

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from polls.views import BasePollView, AnotherPollView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', BasePollView.as_view()),
    url(r'^another-url/$', AnotherPollView.as_view())
]
```

`/polls/` -> BasePollView

`/polls/another-url/` -> AnotherPollView